# Syntax error in JavaScript using Dreamweaver 

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have a JavaScript code in Dreamweaver, but it tells me there's a syntax error on line 2. Where's the problem?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/rates/rates.css" />
<script src="scripts/rates/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#responsecontainer").load("scripts/rates/ratesresult_alb.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#responsecontainer").load('scripts/rates/ratesresult_alb.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 1800000);
});
</script>
<div id="responsecontainer">
</div>
```

the same script works on a site [ak-invest.com](http://ak-invest.com) and in the new website does not work http://69.73.130.182/~akinvest/index.php/en/kembimi-valutor

Comment: Provide complete message of your error.

Comment: No errors present (http://jsfiddle.net/nEWRY/)... are you sure it gives that error when you try *this* code?

Comment: syntax error, line 2 of what file? if the error was on the html page, wouldn't line 2 be around the opening html tag?

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing any syntax errors in the code presented.  Are you sure that jquery is loading?  Try adding a simple script to replace your current one:

```
alert($);
```

This should alert something if jquery is loaded.

You could also check in the html panel of firebug to make sure the libary is being loaded.

Another solution would be to load jquery from a known source such as the Google CDN so that you know you have it.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/rates/rates.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#responsecontainer").load("scripts/rates/ratesresult_alb.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#responsecontainer").load('scripts/rates/ratesresult_alb.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 1800000);
});
</script>
<div id="responsecontainer">
</div>
```

Comment: You're on the boundary here. Many people would argue this is a comment.

Comment: Actually I think this solution has a fighting chance.  The syntax seems correct and I'm betting jquery is not loaded correctly.

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I said "Many people" and not "me" :) After some testing this answer does indeed seem the highest probable cause. +1.

Comment: @Truth thanks for not simply skimming the answer and down voting.  I appreciate you considering the merit of the answer.  I have stumbled upon this problem a bunch in the past when first learning jquery.  I will update the answer to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<script src="scripts/rates/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

to :

```
<script src="scripts/rates/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: HTML5 allows this syntax. So your answer has little merit.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions may not detect the jquery way of accessing variables and elements. You can ignore those errors and see if your script actually works. Did your script works well, despite of those errors?

Alternatively try changing adding type attribute as posted by Mateusz.

Comment: "Syntax Error"s are fatal. It's not something that would allow a script to progress (unless of course, OP is exaggerating with his description).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="../scripts/rates/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

or

```
<script src="./scripts/rates/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: His relative URL syntax is fine. Nothing tells you it's on a different directory than expected.

Comment: May be it's fine but I remember bumping into this problem and this solved it for me. May be for him too.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is almost certainly going to be in the included js file.  And it looks like you didn't write it (it's a jquery library, right?) so the likelihood of there really being a syntax error in the file is rather low.

Therefore, what is actually happening is the file isn't at the path you're looking for it (it's a relative URI), and a HTML 404 page of some sort is being parsed as JavaScript instead of the JavaScript file itself.

Most probably.

Comment: No, when a file isn't found and a 404 is returned, the browser will ignore the contents of the file (even if there are any, which there shouldn't be). The problem is, his methods rely on that library, and without it, they aren't defined and trigger errors.

Comment: Ha ha, only if a 404 is served as a 404.  Some are served as 200.

Comment: Also, you won't get a syntax error in that case, you will get a object expected or equivalent.  Not a syntax error.

Comment: JQuery does not create any new syntax for JavaScript.

Comment: I doubt it, it would be a reference error if $ was not defined at all.